# Safari font bug? Text is aligning to the right css does nothing

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, text-alignment

I'm having this issue with a font and it not styling correctly. With another font it looks right.

For whatever reason it's moving the text to the right, as if it has margin-left:100px; It has NOTHING that is doing this.

This only happens in Safari apple devices.
As you can see from the image it's like it's floated right that's the html and css nothing there speaks to me as being an issue. Except the parent containers contain css allowing them to do 3d .. perseptive etc... could that cause an issue? (I turned this off with no effect)

```
   <button onclick="openMap()" class="enter">ENTER SITE NOW</button>
max-width: 300px;
width: 100%;
margin: 10% auto;
display: block;
font-size: 2.6em;
color: #f6af5f;
border: 0;
padding: 8px 0;
background-color: #4098a5;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 2px rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.51);
```

[image]

Comment: The code you posted (which is incomplete) works just fine in both Firefox and Safari. (Created a page with the button, and set the CSS you provided inside `button {}`- displayed exactly the same in both Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Its the font i imagine , Franchise bold.

Comment: Then you should provide a complete code-sample, with a link to the font, so it would be possible to replicate the bug.